# Difference between registerClass and registerNib UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` which shows 3 different types of custom cells. Each cell is defined in separate xib. Before i used to use registerClass to register cell class with the `UICollectionView`. Inside initialiser of cell, i used to load view from nib file. With this approach few random crashes were recorded when it went to dequeue cell in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and exception was

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named (null)'

To be precise above exception occurred when it tried to load cell from the nib. Now i replaced `registerClass` with `registerNib`, to register nib file again cell identifier for `UICollectionView` and remove nib loading code from cell initialiser. Since then above crash hasn't been reported again.

May i know what is actually difference in way registerClass and registerNib? Also what is the best way of specifying cells for `UICollectionView`?

Comment: What does the documentation say? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the cell class was written in code, use the registerClass: method. 
In the event that the cell is contained within an Interface Builder NIB file, the registerNib: method is used instead.

Comment: And if both are true?

Comment: @lulian registerNib

Comment: if you are using xib for a cell, use only register nib. If you call register class after register nib, there might be an issue like the app crashing